# Does go directive in go.mod file only defines which version of compiler (syntax/semantic) will be used or also the version of the standard library?

Tags: go

As I understand, with `go` directive/line in the go.mod file we can define which version of the language we are using in the module. Based on it, the compiler will set different flags and interpret the source code based on the rules (syntax/semantic) that were available in that version.

However, what I'm interested in is whether the version of the standard library is also defined and changed with the `go` directive/line, or will the latest version always be used, that is, the one that I have in Go toolchain?

Comment: The `go` directive behavior varies by version. All the rules are clearly spelled out in [the documentation](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go). The standard library is part of the installed go version -- there is no "latest" std library, you have the version you installed.

Comment: @JimB Since the standard library also changes with each version of the golang toolchain, not just the compiler, and we can define with the golang directive the language specification we want to use, my question is whether that will change the version of the standard library as well, or is the standard library always "latest" that I installed. For example, if I have a 1.22 golang toolchain and write `go 1.19` in go.mod, it will use the 1.19 language spec, but will it also use the version of the standard library that came in that 1.19?

Comment: You can’t use the std library from a newer toolchain than the compiler, because it may use features not supported by that compiler. Maybe this doc answers your question: https://go.dev/doc/toolchain

Comment: @JimB I know I can't use newer, but I am interested in whether I can use previous versions of std library, like I can use previous versions of language specification by defining `go` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go` directive affects only language features, not the library.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    sl := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    pos, ok := slices.BinarySearch(sl, 2)
    fmt.Println(pos, ok)
}
```

`slices` lib was added to go 1.21. Set `go 1.18` in go.mod and run this code with go 1.21 of 1.22. Result is

```
1 true
```

Try an older version of go (mine was 1.19):

```
main.go:5:2: package slices is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/slices)
```

Comment: Thanks, the question now is how the program with `go 1.18` in go.mod file can compile with go 1.22 (standard library is also 1.22; it has `go 1.22` in go.mod) since the requirement is that all dependencies must have less or equal version than the main module. It looks like this requirement does not to apply to the standard library?

Comment: @LeaBit `std` is an implicit dependency. It is not listed by `go list -m all`, thus the requirement of the maximal go version among dependencies doesn't apply to the standard library.